# C++Builder Make a pdf file with a REST api response

Tags: api, rest, pdf, c++builder

I'm using RAD Studio C++Builder and I need to retrieve a PDF file from a REST API.

Testing with the Postman site, in the body of the response I see the PDF fine and can save it.

Going through C++Builder, I can't save the PDF.

This is my code:

```cpp
TFileStream *FStream;
FStream = new TFileStream("c:\\tmp\\test.pdf", fmCreate);
FStream->Write(this->RESTResponse1->Content.c_str(), RESTResponse1->ContentLength);
delete FStream;
```

Here is the response from the API:

```http
Connection=keep-alive
Date=Wed, 19 Oct 2022 13:17:11 GMT
Content-Length=15891
Content-Type=application/pdf
Vary=Origin
Content-Disposition=attachment; filename*=utf-8''-HUGO-concentr%C3%A9_bien-%C3%AAtre-Maux_de_t%C3%AAte-8ml-de0752a5-21c4-49a6-9fa7-1183e9f1ed0d.pdf
X-Frame-Options=DENY
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
Referrer-Policy=same-origin
Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

How to get the file, or the contents of the file, and save it?

Comment: "*Going through C++Builder, I can't save the pdf*" - why not? What is the actual problem you are having with doing so? What does your code look like? Which REST framework are you using? Please be more specific.

Comment: API usage is new to me.

Replacing content with rawbyte worked perfectly, I have my correct document.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `TRESTResponse::Content` property is the wrong choice to read from when dealing with non-textual data. Use the `TRESTResponse::RawBytes` property instead.